# Selenium send_keys says: Element is not currently interactable and may not be manipulated

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

I want to send key to a login form. the problem is that an error says:

```
Element is not currently interactable and may not be manipulated
```

This is my code:

```
url = 'http://tx3.travian.ir'
hero_url = 'http://tx3.travian.ir/spieler.php?uid=19865'
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(r'phantomjs/bin/phantomjs')
try:
    driver.set_page_load_timeout(15)
    driver.get(url)
except:
    Debug.PrintException()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
username = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.NAME, 'name')))
password = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.NAME, 'password')))
username.send_keys('user')
password.send_keys('pass')
login_btn = driver.find_element_by_id('s1')
login_btn.click()
driver.get(hero_url)
driver.close()
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You defined `WebDriverWait` but you never use it

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
username = wait.until(expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located((By.NAME, 'name')))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `click` at input box and then Enter text.

sometimes, `thread.sleep(ms)` in java also helps.

Answer (score 0):

I have used your own code and made 5 adjustments as follows:

1. Set the `window_size` to `(1400,1000)`
2. For `username` field instead of `(By.NAME, 'name')` I have used `(By.XPATH, "//input[@name='name']")`
3. For `password` field instead of `(By.NAME, 'password')` I have used `(By.XPATH, "//input[@name='password']")`
4. For `login_btn` button instead of `find_element_by_id('s1')` I have used `find_element_by_xpath("//button[@id='s1']")`
5. Finally, I have added a `print` statement to confirm the End of Script.
6. Here is the working code block:

   ```
   from selenium import webdriver
   from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
   from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
   from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


   url = 'http://tx3.travian.ir'
   hero_url = 'http://tx3.travian.ir/spieler.php?uid=19865'
   driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path=r'C:\\Utility\\phantomjs-2.1.1-windows\\bin\\phantomjs.exe')
   try:
       driver.set_page_load_timeout(15)
       driver.set_window_size(1400,1000)
       driver.get(url)
   except:
   #     Debug.PrintException()
       pass
   wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
   username = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@name='name']")))
   password = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@name='password']")))
   username.send_keys('user')
   password.send_keys('pass')
   login_btn = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@id='s1']")
   login_btn.click()
   driver.get(hero_url)
   driver.close()
   print("Driver Closed")
   ```
7. This code block prints the following on my console:

   ```
   Driver Closed
   ```

Comment: Name have high priority over xpath